# Joining Line Breaks in FASTA file With Condition in SED/AWK/Perl one-liner

Tags: linux, perl, unix, sed, awk

I have a data that looks like this

```
> sq1
foofoofoobar
foofoofoo
> sq2
quxquxquxbar
quxquxquxbar
quxx
> sq3
paxpaxpax
pax
```

What I want to do is to join them into one lines:

```
> sq1 foofoofoobarfoofoofoo
> sq2 quxquxquxbarquxquxquxbarquxx
> sq3 paxpaxpaxpax
```

I tried this code but fail.

```
sed -e 'te' -e 'H;$!d;:e' -e 'x;/^$/d;s/\n//g'
```

What's the right way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$ awk '/^>/&&NR>1{print "";}{ printf "%s",/^>/ ? $0" ":$0 }' file 
> sq1 foofoofoobarfoofoofoo
> sq2 quxquxquxbarquxquxquxbarquxx
> sq3 paxpaxpaxpax
```

Comment: there is remaining whitespace in the sequence, e.g. "paxpaxpax pax" instead of "paxpaxpaxpax". How can I remove that?

Answer (score 2):

This is one way to do what you want using `sed`:

```
sed -n '1{x;d;x};${H;x;s/\n/ /1;s/\n//g;p;b};/^>/{x;s/\n/ /1;s/\n//g;p;b};H'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -ne '!/^>/ ? chomp($p) : (chomp $_, $_.=" "); print $p; $p = $_; END{print $p}
```

... which, of course, could be written a lot shorter if desired.

Answer (score 0):

This is might work for you:

```
sed ':a;$!{N;ba};s/\n//g;s/> sq[0-9]*/\n& /g;s/.//' file
```

or this:

```
 sed ':a;$!N;s/\n\([^>]\)/\a\1/;ta;s/\a/ /;s///g;P;D' file
```

or this:

```
 awk -vRS='> sq' '{sub(/^/,RS);sub(/\n/," ");gsub(/\n/,"")};NR>1' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Shortest `sed` solution what I was able to find:

```
sed -n '/^>/!{H;$!b};s/$/ /;x;1b;s/\n//g;p'
```