# AWK join lines between record separator

Tags: unix, awk

I'm new to awk and have a question. I have a file that uses > as a record separator and below the record separator are random strings. Essentially what I would like to do is use awk to print the record separator and join the strings below the record separator.

```
Example file:

input:
>1
AAAA
BB
CCCCCCC
>2
AA
BBBBBBB
CCCC
...

output:
>1
AAAABBCCCCCCC
>2
AABBBBBBBCCCC
...
```

I have this awk program which works when there are set number of lines below the record separator (as in the first example):

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS = "\n"; RS = ">" } {print ">"$1 } {print $2$3$4}' file
```

Is there a way I can use awk to account for any number of strings that might appear below the record separator?

```
Example:
input:
>1
AAAAAA
BBB
CCCCCCCC
DDDD
FFF
>2
AAAAA
CCC
...

output:
>1 
AAAAAABBBCCCCCCCCDDDDFFF
>2
AAAAACCC
...
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Joining Line Breaks in FASTA file With Condition in SED/AWK/Perl one-liner](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2360289/joining-line-breaks-in-fasta-file-with-condition-in-sed-awk-perl-one-liner)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an `awk`

```
awk '/^>/ {print (NR==1?"":RS)$0;next} {printf "%s",$0}' file
>1
AAAAAABBBCCCCCCCCDDDDFFF
>2
AAAAACCC
```

Comment: This solution works very nicely…thank you for your help.

Comment: Nice, but maybe add a `"%s"` on `printf` :)

Comment: @HåkonHægland Added `%s` to make it more robust. And added `^>` to prevent error if there are `>` within the line.

Answer (score 2):

You can loop from 2 to `NF` which is a built-in variable for the number of fields.

Print them with printf() to avoid outputting a newline. Then printf() one newline at the end of the record.

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS = "\n"; RS = ">" } 
    { print ">"$1 } 
    { for(i=2; i<NF; ++i) printf($(i)); }
    { printf("\n"); }' file
```

Comment: This solution gives me a line with a single `>`  then a blank line, then the records starting from `>1`, not sure why.  I would have change `printf("\n");` to just `print ""`

Comment: It creates a blank line because `>` is a record separator, not a record leader. Therefore there's a "record" of zero characters before the first `>`.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '
    BEGIN  {RS=">"; FS="\n"; OFS=""} 
    NR > 1 {$1 = $1 FS; print RS, $0}
' file
```